# Unable to find form Variable using Jquery append

Tags: jquery, jsp

We are using jquery ".append" methods to show more records (Pagination) while scrolling as shown below:

```
$.get(URL,function(data){    
    $(".daily_list").append(data);
}
 });
```

Now pagination is working fine but when we are trying to access form variable of the appended content then we are getting below error message:

**"Error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference"**

though we are able to access the parent form variables (before scrolling) . Also when we access the "view source" of the page, we are unable to find out the appended content.

Please suggest us how can we access form variable of the appended content as we would like to make it as the part of the original form.

Comment: If the code to get the details from the appended form is already executed before it is appended, it will not be able to access that element. For example if $(".button").click(func.. is executed before .append() then it will not work on the appended form.

Comment: Hi, each section (parent & appended) code is having following form variable:     <div class="add_comment"><html:textarea property="commentBodyTxt" rows= "8" cols ="62"> </html:textarea>   
 <html:button property="Submit"  onclick='<%= "javascript:saveComment(" + updateID +","+dailyCounter + ");"%>' >Submit</html:button>                                                                                          Now we are trying to access "commentBodyTxt" value while pressing the button ..and it is saying that ""Error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: do anyone have any suggestion  on this?

Comment: We are using code as follow

<html:form action="searchCollegeResult.do" method="post" styleId="daily_list1" enctype="multipart/form-data">  

under this we are having div tag  

<div class="daily_list"> 
---- 

<html:textarea property="commentBodyTxt" rows= "8" cols ="62"> </html:textarea> 
<html:button property="Submit" onclick='<%= "javascript:saveComment(" + updateID +","+dailyCounter + ");"%>'   

</div> 
</html:form>
and adding content on scrolling as follow:

var URL="/dailyUpdateListLoding.do?mode=few&page="+pageNumber;
$.get(URL,function(data){
 ---
    $('.daily_list').append(data);

Comment: It would be good to put your code in the question itself, I dont see the saveComment function.

Answer (score 0):

Let me describe it again here:
Our parent form look like :

```
<html:form action="searchCollegeResult.do" method="post" styleId="formList" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The text area elements is sitting within the form opening and closing tags and looks like:

```
  <div class="daily_list">
    <html:textarea property="commentBodyTxt" rows= "8" cols ="62"> </html:textarea>     <html:button property="Submit"  onclick='<%= "javascript:saveComment(" + updateID +","+dailyCounter + ")"%>' >Submit</html:button>
    </div>
    </html:form>
```

Implemented pagination as shown below:
 1. appending content on the div segment as shown below $('.daily_list').append(data). It is not working
2. also try to append content on form  $('#formList').append(data). It is also not working

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
/*
*   If nothing is loading right now AND scroll has reached bottom of page
*   load data from backend and set loading = true
*/
if (isLoading==false && $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()-$("#footer").height()) {
//set loading true
// [you can also display any loading image or anything you want]

if (dailyUpdateResultCounterIndex >=dailyUpdateResultCount) {

$(".nomorerecord").show();
$(".loadingMore").hide();
$(".loadingText").hide();

}else {

isLoading=true;
$(".loadingText").show();

//URL from where more data needs to be fetched
//you can add custom parameters to it too
var URL="/dailyUpdateListLoding.do?mode=few&page="+pageNumber;

$.get(URL,function(data){


$('.daily_list').append(data);
isLoading=false;
$(".loadingText").hide();

//add more results
results+=recordsPerRequest;
dailyUpdateResultCounterIndex+=recordsPerRequest;

if(results%MAX_RECORDS==0){
isLoading = true;
$(".loadingText").hide();
$(".loadingMore").show();
}
});

}

}
});
</script>
```

dailyUpdateListLoding.do is having following content:

```
<html:form action="searchCollegeResult.do" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<html:textarea property="commentBodyTxt" rows= "8" cols ="62"> </html:textarea>     <html:button property="Submit"  onclick='<%= "javascript:saveComment(" + updateID +","+dailyCounter + ")"%>' >Submit</html:button>

</html:form>
```

Now we are able to print parent form variable (on submit)but unable to access the content which we are appending through jquery.